# API key Google Cloud Maps/Geocode/Geolocation

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform, google-geocoding-api

I am working in one app that show one map and take locations from geolocation and traduce with geocode.. All that is working fine.
The problem is that I can not restrict the key.

*If I choose the restrict ->> Apps to android = I get maps working / No more.*

*If I choose the restrict ->> URL ref HTTP = I get Geoco/Geolo Without Maps.*

So here I dont know how restrict the Api key and get all working.

More info..
I am using geolocation&geocoding with a ***HttpURLConnection*** to get the response with JSON.
And using maps with the class ***MapFragment***

***EDIT:***

I think the only solution for this is handle 2 keys for the same application.. 
Still looking for some solutions or improvement.

---

*This was a bad idea.. Never handle 2 keys for same platform.  Still no solution for handle restriction on the 3 APIs*

Comment: @xomena Yeah I do not see that when I was looking, Thanks.. But you need create 2 keys ? You can not restrict the key twice.. is for android apps or IP

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to restrict the key so that it is only visible to your app. Google provides a key for the web as well as mobile apps. Try using the API console in your developer account. Normally you have SHA1 and package names that prevents public usage of map API.

Comment: Yes I am develop a mobile app, but I cant use geolocation&geocode with the restriction for android apps, i think because the usage of HTTP request. I am using the SHA-1 to get restriction on android apps. // With your answer i think.. Geolocation&Geocode is only for web ??

Comment: Basically, google geolocation is a service that is either available to mobile app or web. Of course, you need the internet in order to use geolocation. It is a  web service.

Comment: I am looking for restrict the key. I have all the APIs working.